# How to get value of array based on id from same collection in mongodb

Tags: mongodb-query

How to get value of array based on id from same collection in mongodb
. Here `"linkedBy"` is array of
`"storyId"`. So in result in `"linkedBy"` array instead of only `"storyId"` need to fetch all details of that `"storyId"`.

collection 1:-

```
{
 "_id" : ObjectId("6130f4f16dc8c60fa554c37e"),
    "storyId" : "101",
    "storyTitle" : "story 1",
    "storyPriority" : "",
    "storyPoints" : "0",
    "linkedBy" : [],
},
{
 "_id" : ObjectId("2345f4f16dc8c60fa554c37e"),
    "storyId" : "102",
    "storyTitle" : "story 2",
    "storyPriority" : "",
    "storyPoints" : "0",
    "linkedBy" : [101],
}
```

expected result :-

```
{
 "_id" : ObjectId("6130f4f16dc8c60fa554c37e"),
    "storyId" : "101",
    "storyTitle" : "story 1",
    "storyPriority" : "",
    "storyPoints" : "0",
    "linkedBy" : [],
},
{
 "_id" : ObjectId("2345f4f16dc8c60fa554c37e"),
    "storyId" : "102",
    "storyTitle" : "story 2",
    "storyPriority" : "",
    "storyPoints" : "0",
    "linkedBy" : [
      {
        "_id" : ObjectId("6130f4f16dc8c60fa554c37e"),
        "storyId" : "101",
        "storyTitle" : "story 1",
        "storyPriority" : "",
        "storyPoints" : "0",
        "linkedBy" : [],
      }
    ],
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having `"storyId"` and `"linkedBy"` values be different types is a bit unfortunate, but not insurmountable.  It's also not clear how you want to handle possible circular references and/or recursion depth.

Anyway, here's one way to generate your desired output (as I understand it) using [`"$graphLookup"`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/graphLookup/).

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$graphLookup": {
      "from": "collection",
      "startWith": {
        "$map": {
          "input": "$linkedBy",
          "as": "storyIdInt",
          "in": {
            "$toString": "$$storyIdInt"
          }
        }
      },
      "connectFromField": "linkedBy",
      "connectToField": "storyId",
      "as": "linkedBy",
      "maxDepth": 0
    }
  }
])
```

Try it on [mongoplayground.net](https://mongoplayground.net/p/XRHmPGujsK7).

Comment: is it possible for you to provide answer in below format (i.e bsonDocument foramt)

var lookupOperation = new BsonDocument{{"$lookup", new BsonDocument {
                    {"from", "PhoenixStory" },
                    {"localField", "dependentStories"},
                    {"foreignField", "storyId"},
                    {"as", "dependent"}} }
            };

Comment: @TasneemDesai So you are using `C#` (I'm not a `C#` user ... I just Googled `BsonDocument` and found it [here](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.12/reference/bson/bson_document/)?  You want an answer using `"$lookup"` and _not_ `"$graphLookup"`?  I don't see `"dependentStories"` in your example documents - if it's there would you edit/add some example documents?

Comment: Below is my working copy.. thanks for solution                                     

      var linkedByLookup = new BsonDocument{ {"$graphLookup", new BsonDocument {
       {"from", "collectionName" },
       {"startWith","$linkedBy" },
         {"connectFromField", "linkedBy" },
         {"connectToField", "storyId" },
         {"as", "linkedByLookup"},
         {"maxDepth", 0 }
        }
      } };